# come to a close pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation

How to pronounce correctly **s** of close in idiom "come to a close"?
Is it /kləʊ**s**/ or /kləʊ**z**/.

I'm asking because in a film I heard /kləʊz/ and I thought it is was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good question! There are several meanings of close.  The adjectival meaning near and the noun meaning a confined space or courtyard, are pronounced with an s. Then there is the verb and noun relating to closure or completion: this is pronounced with a z.

In this expression, we are using close as a noun, in the sense of completion, for example

```
the performance was drawing to a close when the stage collapsed
```

as it relates to closure, we use the z-sound at the end of close.